# How to avoid Memory Leak with returning const char *

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a function which is used a million times in my code and there is a memory leak in it.

It takes a `const wchar_t*` as input and returns a `const char*`.
Now I understand that this pointer returned (`const char*`) would be required to get an explicit `delete[]` from the calling function (but I cannot afford it) as this would mean I need to change it on all locations.

The code is like:

```
inline const char * W2N(const wchar_t* wstr)
{
  int cw=lstrlenW(wstr);

  if (cw==0) 
  {
      CHAR *psz=new CHAR[1]; *psz='\0'; return psz;
  }

  int cc=WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,wstr,cw,NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
  if (cc==0) return NULL;

  CHAR *psz=new CHAR[cc+1];
  cc=WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,wstr,cw,psz,cc,NULL,NULL);
  if (cc==0) 
  {
      delete[] psz; return NULL;
  }

  psz[cc]='\0';
  return psz;
}
```

Is there anything that I can do around this function to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Agreed tobi303, but the pointer psz returned at the end is causing leak as it was never deallocated.

Comment: Do you know when the client calling function will have finished with the memory returned by `W2N()`?

Comment: Why not use `std::string` instead of `char *`?

Comment: By using a function allocating memory you 'sign a contract' and take the responsibility to deallocate it when necessary. Your code is in a bad shape and any tricky solution would make it even worse. Change the code so that your function returns `std::unique_ptr<char[]> fact(new char[size]);` (assuming you are in the C++ environment) or return std::string

Answer (score 3):

You can, and you should, wrap your pointer inside a [`std::unique_ptr<char[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). This will solve your exact problem, in an idiomatic C++ way.

This will change your function like this:

```
inline std::unique_ptr<char[]> W2N(const wchar_t *wstr) {
    int cw = lstrlenW(wstr);

    if(cw == 0) {
        auto psz = std::make_unique<char[]>(1);
        psz[0] = '\0';
        return psz;
    }
    int cc = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr, cw, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if(cc == 0)
        return nullptr;
    auto psz = std::make_unique<char[]>(cc + 1);
    cc = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr, cw, psz, cc, NULL, NULL);
    if(cc == 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    psz[cc] = '\0';
    return psz;
}
```

This, of course, assumes that you have access to a C++14 compliant compiler (for `std::make_unique`), or at least C++11 compliant (for `std::unique_ptr`).

Of course, as stated in the comments, you could return a `std::string`. If you do so, beware that returning `nullptr` or `NULL` from the function will probably segfault.

Answer (score -1):

Without trying to solve this for multithreading, a global char buffer big enough to hold your largest string and the \0 returned would make for a fixed "leak".

Comment: While it would work, I'd really not recommend this for anything else than an embedded environment where you try to avoid dynamic memory allocation. This is looking for trouble in the context of Windows OS APIs, etc., as OP is using it. (It is looking for trouble in embedded as well, but sometimes there is no other way in that environment...)

Comment: Was I supposed to work it out for multithreading, multi-process,  check buffer overflow, encoding or more?

Comment: no, but you should not suggest a global buffer in a WinAPI application where there is an event loop and all kinds of less obvious ways in which control can flow or all kinds of opaque functions which can accidentally mutate your buffer.

Comment: Then that's a bug in Windows that needs fixing--doubt it.

Comment: No, that's not a bug in Windows. It's just making it more difficult to not shoot yourself in the foot. All the Windows functions work as expected, but it can very easily happen that you forget what the developers (Windows and your app's functions) promised and get unexpected results as consequence if you start having global buffers which can be changed from any place and live for the duration of the program.

Comment: Global buffers don't get changed by gremlins but by design.

Comment: This conversation is getting nowhere. I'm not saying buffers change themselves. I'm saying programmers forget assumptions made elsewhere in a 10kloc code base and accidentally break assumptions about how and when the global buffer is used. If you believe only "bad" programmers make that kind of mistake, I really don't want to work with you.